# How to set table width percentage using office js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in, word-addins

I am working on Office JS word addin project.
I am creating a table with 4 columns. I want to set width percentage to 30%,30%,20%,20% respectively. How can I set table width percentake like this. Below is a sample code I am using for table creation

```
function createTable() {    
  Word.run(function (context) {
    var body = context.document.body;
    var Table = body.insertTable(2, array.length, Word.InsertLocation.start, [array]);    
    return context.sync();
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word JS API has no capability (yet) for specificying how a table's columns should behave. It just assumes the default, which means the columns will adjust to their content.

So the only solution is to work with the Word Open XML. Simplest would probably be to insert the entire table (at least the basic structures) using the OOXML methods of the Word JS API, rather than trying to change (replace) an existing table.

The column width, when set as a percentage, is controlled in a number of elements that define the table. This [link](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableWidth.php) to OfficeOpenXML.com may be useful.

The following Word Open XML, generated using the COM object model and the property `Table.Range.WordOpenXML`, illustrates the basic table structures of a table formatted as a percent of the page width (`w:tblW`), and cells as a percentage of the table's width (`w:tcW`). The table had two columns, set to 20% and 80%. Note that Word will minimally adjust the percentages based on its layout algorithm, so the actual percentage used in always an approximation.

The `w:gridCol` settings also reflect these proportions.

Besides the percentages, the `w:type` attribute is important. It tells Word how to interpret the width settings: `w:type="pct"` specifies "percent".

The values may see quite large, that's because they're a ***fifths of a percent***. So 5000 is 100%.

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
           <w:tblW w:w="5000" w:type="pct"/>
           <w:tblLayout w:type="fixed"/>
           <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
  </w:tblPr>
  <w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="944"/><w:gridCol w:w="3700"/></w:tblGrid>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1016" w:type="pct"/></w:tcPr>
          <w:p/>
    </w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="3984" w:type="pct"/></w:tcPr>
          <w:p/>
    </w:tc><
  /w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

Comment: Agreed but my table creation will be dynamic based on data I receive from one api. This api will give me all column values along with width. in OOXML I need to set a pre-defined template and table will be drawn based on that table definition. How can I dynamically set width and draw the table?

Comment: See the reply I just wrote to your question about the data part. If you don't have the background to "loop" data into XML you need to take a step back and learn that. It's a many-facetted topic that is much too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use autoFitWindow() function under table.